# How to mimic Facebook's "Like" feature in WebSocket

Tags: java, facebook, websocket, atmosphere

I developed a proof of concept application that uses WebSocket to mimic the functionality of Facebook.

If on Facebook someone "likes" a picture, I see the notification on my page right away without me refreshing the page. Is this being done by WebSocket?  What strategy is this  adopting - pub/sub?

The application I developed is in Java and I came across [Atmosphere Framework](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere#readme). I'm not sure which sample I should review from [their vast list of examples on GitHub](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/tree/master/samples) to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Without Facebook API, we'll have to find a certain way:

On a dedicated server, since you are not using Facebook API, I would use an auto refresher that refreshes the Facebook page every interval of time and put the number of likes in a database. 
Then, use AJAX on your website that communicates with a PHP file on server.

Comment: redundantly refreshing the page seems like a bad practice. Also, I'm not necessarily looking for a sample using facebook. But just the functionality that facebook uses...

Comment: ah sorry I misunderstood the question! Then you should be using ajax. Facebook uses Ajax.